# "failed to insert" Error When Copying Image to Bucket

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create an image to a bucket, but it consistently fails like so:

```
ami@snowflake:/work/ami$ gcloud compute images create snowflake-image-1 --source-uri gs://snowflake-main-image-1/snowflake-image-1.image.tar.gz
NAME PROJECT ALIAS DEPRECATED STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - failed to insert the following resources within 300s: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/snowflake-1056/global/images/snowflake-image-1
```

I've deleted the image and retried it several times, but the error is consistent.

When I list the images, it appears `PENDING` like this:

```
ami@snowflake:/work/ami$ gcloud compute images list
NAME                                              PROJECT           ALIAS              DEPRECATED STATUS
snowflake-image-1                                 snowflake-1056                                  PENDING
...
```

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?